# how to explode object through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code and I want it explode. How can I explode the code in Jquery? I want explode `$write` because I want to pass `id` through javascript. It is an object and I only get `id` through its gave all things.

```
var $write = $(':input').on('click', function(){
        var id = this.id;
        shift = false,
        capslock = false;
        var str = new Array();
        temp = str.split(" : ");
        console.log(temp);
```

Actually I got in console this code:

```
Array [ button,
    input#country.form-control,
    input#itemNo_1.form-control.autocomplete_txt.pdc.divide.ui-autocomplete-input,
    input#itemNo_2.form-control.autocomplete_txt.pdc.divide,
    input#itemNo_3.form-control.autocomplete_txt.pdc.divide,
    button.btn.btn-search,
    input,
    input,
    input,
    input, … ]
```

and I want only `id` from it.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).id is not a function

Comment: @vlaz `this.id` is correct.

Comment: I don't see any way you could be getting that output. `str` is an array, not a string, so `str.split(" : ")` should report an error.

Comment: What do you mean by `explode $write`? The return value of `.on()` is the jQuery object that you're adding the event handler to.

Comment: i want pass here( $(':input') id instead of tagname.now any solution

Comment: @Barmar damn, my jQuery seems to be rusty. Thanks.

Comment: $write is object so thats why when i print on console thats show meArray [ button, input#country.form-control, input#itemNo_1.form-control.autocomplete_txt.pdc.divide.ui-autocomplete-input, input#itemNo_2.form-control.autocomplete_txt.pdc.divide, input#itemNo_3.form-control.autocomplete_txt.pdc.divide, button.btn.btn-search, input, input, input, input, … ]. i want only id from it

Comment: @VivekPandey That's correct, it's the jQuery collection of the elements that match the `:input` selector.

Comment: `$write.map(el => el.id).get()` will return an array of all the IDs.

Comment: how use it on keyboard

Answer (score 0):

To get the IDs of all the elements in `$write`, you can use `.map()`:

```
var ids = $write.map((i, el) => el.id).get();
```

`.get()` at the end is needed because jQuery's `.map()` method returns a jQuery collection, and `.get()` converts that to an array.

```js
var ids = $(":input").map((i, el) => el.id).get();
$("#output").text(JSON.stringify(ids));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1">
<select id="select2">
  <option></option>
  <option val="1">Selection1</option>
  <option val="2">Selection2</option>
</select>
<input id="anotherInput">
<div>
  List of input IDs:
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i got empty  Array [] but i want id from it. how is it possible

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that jQuery .map has the index argument first.

Comment: so how i can use

Comment: thanks for all literally i just near by result please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Use it for what? You can iterate over the array.